# Move a shape in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to move a shape in WinForm. I am achieving it with the following algorithm:

```
virtual public void Move(Graphics g)
{
    Center.X += _dx;
    if (Center.X - Size / 2 < 0)
    {
        _dx = _dx * -1;
    }
    else if (Center.X + Size / 2 > Form1.CanvasWidth)
    {
        _dx = _dx * -1;
    }

    Center.Y += _dy;
    if (Center.Y - Size / 2 < 0)
    {
        _dy = _dy * -1;
    }
    else if (Center.Y + Size / 2 > Form1.CanvasHeigth)
    {
        _dy = _dy * -1;
    }
    Draw(g, _currColor);
}
```

where `dx = 1` and `dy = 1`. The object moves as desired. But I want to now control the speed between 100 pixels - 1000 pixels per second. I try to update the interval of my timer to achieve this but I dont see any significant change.

```
myTimer.Interval = 1000/SpeedPx;
```

Where `SpeedPx` is the value between 100 - 1000.

```
private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    Form1 mainForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().SingleOrDefault();
    using (var g = mainForm.CreateGraphics())
    {
        g.Clear(mainForm._background);
        mainForm._shapes[mainForm._shapeIndex].Move(g);
    } 
}
```

The following lines in my mouse click event:

```
 myTimer.Interval = 1000/SpeedPx;
 myTimer.Start();
```

Comment: We can't see what your timer is actually doing.  Show all relevant code.

Comment: Where does the Graphics object come from? _Where SpeedPx is the value between 100 - 1000_ this makes the Interval go between 1 and 10 but the minimum is 15-25!! (Timer can't goes any faster!!)

Comment: @TaW how should I go about to achieve the speed between 100 - 1000 pixels per second?

Comment: change the speed delta to suit your needs. for 25ms = 40fps it would have to be 100/40 or 1000/40. I suggest keeping track of the locations in float variables!

Comment: Changing the values of dy & dx could also be used to modify the speed.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a System.Timer then the Timer interval is in milliseconds, so 1000 / 1000 .. 1000 / 100 gives you 1 to 10 milliseconds, the average human won't see much difference.

Comment: Actually you would but the system simply can't do it.